# Ember hook when transitioning from child route to parent route

Tags: ember.js

So I'm inside of an Ember child route, `attendee.search`.

And I have a button there than transitions back to `attendee.index`.

I need to reset the content of the attendee list when the transition occurs, but neither `setupController`, `model`, nor `redirect` are called when going from a child route to its parent.

**How can I run a function every time a user lands on the `attendee` route?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `deactivate` hook on `App.AttendeeSearchRoute`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Fixed it. It was more of a statement than a question.

Answer (score 4):

The `deactivate` hook will get hit when going to any other route.  If you want to know if it's going to the parent specifically, check in the `willTransition` action of `App.AttendeeSearchRoute`

```
  actions: {
    willTransition: function(transition) {
      if(transition.targetName === 'attendee.index') {
        // Going to the parent route...
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Like the explicit